# Run same query on multiple SQL Developer connections

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have multiple oracle sql developer connections which has same sets of tables, view, etc. Every time when there was a change required (etc: update statement for one of the table) I need to manually connected to the connections and run the sql script. I wanted to know if I can automate run the sql script on multiple connections at once (via script etc).

Answer (score 1):

Not today, but we're looking to support this in a future release.

Yes, it's officially on our product roadmap.